# connect to https Web service from CICS thru COBOL program

Tags: web-services, cobol, cics

I am trying to connect to an HTTPS web service through a COBOL-written CICS module. Below is the screenshot. I am getting the error as:

> INVOKE COMMAND IS NOT VALID AND IS NOT TRANSLATED.

[image]

I have moved the webservice name and URI endpoint below before invoking it. Please let me know how to connect properly?

Comment: Please refer to [the documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGMCP_5.1.0/com.ibm.cics.ts.applicationprogramming.doc/commands/dfhp4_invokeservice.html)... There are some attributes missing in your (web)service request.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you've got the full `INVOKE SERVICE` command supplied. The full syntax ([at CICS TS 5.5](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGMCP_5.5.0/reference/commands-api/dfhp4_invokeservice.html)) is:

```
>>-INVOKE-SERVICE(data-value)--CHANNEL(data-value)-------------->

>--OPERATION(data-value)--+--------------------+---------------->
                          +-URI(data-value)----+   
                          '-URIMAP(data-value)-'   

>--+---------------------------------------------+-------------><
   '-SCOPE(data-value)--+----------------------+-'   
                        '-SCOPELEN(data-value)-'
```

You've supplied the service name with `WEBSERVICE`/`SERVICE`, and `URI`, but are lacking the `CHANNEL` to hold the data, and the `OPERATION` to be called on the target webservice's WSDL.

Comment: @sridhar-duriasamy did it work you? If so please mark it correct with the tick/check mark, to help future users.

Comment: No Ben. I am still facing the issue. It seems my Compiler job do not have required CICS load files to compile the newer Web browsing keywords. So checking with my CICS admin team. Will try to finish it and let you know.